# of the following four statements which are true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb R$.

let $f_n(x)$= $n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$

then

1) $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$

2) $f_n$ converges on $\mathbb R$ but not necessarily uniformly

3) $f_n$ converges to derivative of $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

4) there is no guarantee that $f_n$ converges on any open interval

i know that result for any interval so from that i know $(3)$ holds. but how to see for $\mathbb R$.

$(2)$ is also answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$n(f(x+1/n)−f(x)) = \frac{f(x+1/n)−f(x)}{1/n} \to f'(x)$$
(at least) pointwise in $\Bbb R$. And for (1) try with some easy examples.

Comment: yes possibility d is out. but what about uniform convergence?

Comment: @user290972, for the uniform convergence in $[0,1]$ use the mean value theorem.

Comment: @  Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla   any counter example for 1)

Comment: @user290972, check what happens with some $x^n$, $n = 1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: for $x,x^2$ uniformly convergent in $\mathbb R$ but for $x^n$ for   $n\ge 3$ not.

Comment: @ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla i am right?

Comment: @user290972, right. Now, you have the counterexample for (1).